# Editing an attribute referring to a list of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started this little project not that long ago, I've gotten decently far into it however; whenever I try to referece my instance of my class within a list, it says `AttributeError: 'str' has no attribute 'lista'`. In this case its only lista because I was only trying to create 1 list, lista, here is the code and it is kinda lengthy. Having all the code will allow you to fully grasp it and analyze any (even a lot, I already know about my if-else format;I like it simple):

```
class UserInput:
    users=[]

    def __init__(self, name,lista,listb,listc,listd):
        self.name=""
        self.lista=lista
        self.listb=listb
        self.listc=listc
        self.listd=listd

    @classmethod                    #the @classmethod is  a preference for later sub-classes to have the ability to edit the list if need-be
    def create_new_users(cls):
        print("how many users do you want to create")
        x=int(input())
        for _ in range(x):       
            print("assign the users names")
            name = input()
            if name == '' or name.lower()  == 'none':
                raise RuntimeError("name cannot be None or empty")              
            name=cls(name,lista="",listb="",listc="",listd="")
            cls.users.append(name)
        return(name)

    @classmethod  
    def show_users(cls):
        print(UserInput.users)

    @classmethod    
    def set_lists(cls):
        print("Do you want to create lists")
        decision = input()
        print( "select the user you intend on adding lists for")

        namestring = input()             
        for elem in UserInput.users:
            print(vars(UserInput.users[0]))                      
            if decision == "yes":   
                print("how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)")
                decision2= int(input())
                if decision2 == 1:
                    print("what would you like the list to be named?")
                    setattr(UserInput.users[0],'lista',+ namestring)                            
                else:
                     return

            else:
                 return
```

**My Question:** the line, `print(vars(UserInput.users[0]))` shows clearly that a reference to the object is there with the attributes empty, Why isn't it allowing me to edit the object( for the sake of testing this, if you do, enter one user and one list) even when there is a CLEAR reference to the object with `UserInput.users[0]`? Btw when I enter only one user, since its users[0] mainly for testing purposes to get it working,  it does return what the object holds, the vars() function does that

### Applying the code:

```
    from user import UserInput
UserInput.create_new_users()
print(vars(UserInput.users[0]))
UserInput.set_lists()
```

### Resulted

```
how many users do you want to create
1
assign the users names
tim
{'name': '', 'listb': '', 'lista': '', 'listd': '', 'listc': ''}
Do you want to create lists
yes
select the user you intend on adding lists for
tim
{'name': '', 'listb': '', 'lista': '', 'listd': '', 'listc': ''}
how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)
1
what would you like the list to be named?
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    UserInput.set_lists()
  File "C:\Users\Tim\desktop\project ideas\user.py", line 41, in set_lists
    setattr(UserInput.users[0].lista,'UserInput.users[0].lista', namestring)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'UserInput.users[0].lista'
```

`{'name': '', 'listb': '', 'lista': '', 'listd': '', 'listc': ''}` = `vars(UserInput.users[0])`

Comment: Are you not passing self to any of these methods?

Comment: Can you show a few lines of code where you actually use this class and call eg `set_lists`?

Comment: NB: you may want to edit your question: some of the indentation in the code block is messed up, making it harder to read.

Comment: @Evert what I was doing, it messed up bad during paste

Comment: I get `NameError: global name 'namestring' is not defined`. Where does namestring come from?

Comment: It looks like you mixed up tabs and spaces for your indentation. That's why it was so messed up. Never, ever do that in Python. The preferred way of indentation is four spaces.

Comment: its fixed I fixed it man I forgot to change choice to namestring

Comment: I fixed ur issue I mean

Comment: and @evert that was a copy paste issue man I use tabs correctly

Comment: You probably intend `namestring = input("what would you like the list to be named?") instead of the `namestring = input` before that. Otherwise that last print statement doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I copied-pasted your code as it is now, and I don't get any errors. Instead, I end up with `{'listc': '', 'name': '', 'lista': 'e', 'listd': '', 'listb': ''}`, which seems pretty much what is intended.

Comment: Look at your traceback, the `setattr(...)` line. Then look at the code you copy-pasted in your question: they don't match! Your error shows different code than what you copied. Looks like your copy-pasting also fixed your problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want this code to do? The `set_list` method doesn't create any lists. There are no lists excluding the `users` lists in this class, you set the other "lists" as `string`s when you instantiate each one. If you want to create users and keep track of them it would be easier and cleaner to just make a `User` class and create a `users` dictionary/DB to store them.

Comment: @IanAuld, sorry for the late response, im in Okinawa,japan. My issue is that im "attempting " to pull a user from a predefined list,Users, and edit the name to create "Names" for lsits, I haven't gotten to the stage yet where I create lists WITH names, im taking this one step at a time

Comment: @IanAuld I have vars(UserInput.users[0]) so that I can show to you all that the reference is there, that the class object,w/e you name the user been instantiated with no variable,(not really as you can see I had to create lista, b c and d so that I can override them as needed)

Comment: @Evert, the entire point of the vars, as you know, is to show the user the instance variables of a class

Comment: I never mentioned vars. Only thing I'll still say is that your traceback doesn't match your code, and that the code as it is above runs without raising an exception.

Comment: @evert probably because I removed half the function where it allows the user to edit more than one list, I was on a 24hr duty and had a break so I posted this question, I didn't have the time to paste it and space it correctly.This entire question was solved by that one answer below.With it I can edit the lists through a dictionary, not what I had(a list). I appreciate your input, if you have any advice let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 3.3 running this code that I edited and added comments to:

```
class User:  # changed class name to make it clearer
    users = {}

    def __init__(self, name, list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d):  # added underscores to make list name easier to read
        self.name = name
        self.list_a = list_a
        self.list_b = list_b
        self.list_c = list_c
        self.list_d = list_d

    @classmethod  # the @classmethod is a preference for later sub-classes to have the ability to edit the list if need-be
    def create_new_users(cls):
        print("how many users do you want to create")
        x = int(input())
        for _ in range(x):
            name = input("Assign the users names")
            if name == '' or name.lower() == 'none':
                raise RuntimeError("name cannot be None or empty")
            new_user = cls(name, list_a=[], list_b=[], list_c=[], list_d=[])  # changed strings to lists
            cls.users[new_user.name] = new_user  # adds new_user to the dict using the user name as the key

    @classmethod
    def show_users(cls):
        for key in cls.users:
            print(key, cls.users[key])

    @classmethod
    def set_lists(cls):
        choice = input("select the user you intend on adding lists for")  # moved prompts into input()
        for elem in User.users:
            print(vars(User.users[choice]))
            decision2 = int(input("how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4)"))
            if decision2 == 1:
                name_string = input("what would you like the list to be named?")
                setattr(User.users['Ian'], 'list_a', name_string) # see below
                print("you have created 1 list, with the name:%s" %name_string)
```

produces this when run in the shell

```
>>> usr.create_new_users()
how many users do you want to create? 

1
Assign the users names: Ian
>>> print(vars(User.users['Ian']))
{'list_a': [], 'name': 'Ian', 'list_c': [], 'list_d': [], 'list_b': []}
>>> usr.set_lists()
select the user you intend on adding lists for: Ian
{'list_a': [], 'name': 'Ian', 'list_c': [], 'list_d': [], 'list_b': []}
how many lists would you like to create?(up to 4): 1
what would you like the list to be named?
thing
you have created 1 list, with the name:thing
```

I don't think you can change the name of attributes after the class has been created. The line I marked as `see below` just changes the list `list_a` into a string. Even if you could I would recommend against letting users decide the names of them. You would end up with several instances of the same class that could all have different attributes.

If you want you could create one dictionary called `lists` for the class and have users add lists to that dictionary with their choice of name as the key.

Comment: I see now, that makes MUCH more sense than using a list I will just turn it into a dictionary, the fix was so simple;thank you!

Comment: the entire point of this program is to allow multiple users to be created, each with their own lists specific to their interests; its a simple program(in theory, ive messed up a lot as you can see in this question) and its my first.Im still learning, and now I can see that if use a dictionary it will allow me to do what I inetended where a list doesnt

Comment: I also understand what youre saying, I should define what each list name should be and allow users to input the items they want into the lists